# Excel 2013 Add-in only works on First workbook, (When Excel work on same Instance)

Tags: excel, ms-office, add-in

I have a custom excel add-in.

It was perfectly work in office 2010 and olders. But after office 2013 upgrade, Add-in only works first excel. Even i clicked from other workbooks, add-in shows up itself in first work book.

any idea people?

Comment: Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn251093.aspx and http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/keepuserformontop.asp

Comment: Hey Doug, thank for the reply, problem was really iinstance, when i seperate the instances, my add-in started to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, thanks for the @Doug.

If excels work on seperate instances, it works. 
For seperate instance, create a bat file like name excel.bat and

write --> `start "Excel" "c:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\EXCEL.EXE" /e %1` in it.

when you drag and drop your excel in that bat file, excel works from different instance.